# Erc-1155 metadata not working on polyscan mumbai for erc-20 tokens

Tags: solidity, contract-development, etherscan, polygon, erc-1155

I have a erc-1155 contract that manages 2 erc-20 tokens. I am trying to set uri, in format "https://some-url/{id}.json".
According to docs, clients should be able to replace {id} with tokenId and that should be standardized.
However, there is no impact on mumbai polyscan, decimals are not shown in transfers (for 10 with decimals 6, it is showing 10000000).
My expectations were if i specify metadata with "decimals": 6, that mumbai polyscan would recognize this, and show values properly.

My question is, are these expectations correct, or is this not possible? Or is this not possible only on mumbai polyscan?

My metadata looks like this:
{
"name": "Test token",
"decimals": 6,
"description": "Test token"
}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey as much as I know. ERC1155 does not support the concept of decimals.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a few misunderstandings:

First off, ERC20 is not the same as creating fungible tokens on ERC1155 standard, they have completely different APIs. That being said the standard ERC1155 does not feature decimals. But what I'm really hung up on, is how this has anything to do with the uri()?

Comment: Please check erc-1155 eip and look for "decimals" it is stated it is the part of metadata, and clients should process it. For example, open sea shows it correctly, etherscan doesn't. That is what uri has to do with it, uri is for clients to be able to fetch metadata, and decimals with it.

Comment: Okay:  I hadn't considered clients seeking decimals in the metadata for display purposes. In my opinion getting etherscan to display properly is important and i just verified totalSupply() was being used for this there. In the end, technically, the standard does not include decimals but nothing preventing you from implementing how you'd like and then totalSupply() can return a factor of six decimal places. The question then becomes what would you like to actually 'count' as your total supply? Is it token Id? or total tokens across all Id?

Comment: Total supply is not my question. Standard includes decimals for erc-1155 but etherscan doesn't implement it properly. That's the whole thing.

Comment: Again. Standard does NOT include decimals for 1155. You are referring to an example of how one MAY use metadata the uri links to.